# Optimise the update query which exceeds 30 secs of execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a procedure which adds the data to database in case is not present (duplicate). If the data is duplicated then the empty fields in the database will be updated.

eg: first time the entry is

```
 companyname  email_id     contact_name  designation  mobile fax country 

1  abc        xyz@abc.com     xyz          pqr
```

Now if the entry comes second time with some extra data then

```
2  abc       xyz@abc.com     xyz          pqr      0987765  087722   South Africa
```

Now the existing data will be updated only for empty field i.e. only mobile fax and country will be updated in the existing data.

Now my query for updating is as follows:

```
 UPDATE dbo.companyinfo SET companyinfo.companyname=case when companyinfo.companyname='' or companyinfo.companyname=null then RESULT.companyname else companyinfo.companyname end ,
 companyinfo.website= case when companyinfo.website='' OR companyinfo.website IS NULL then RESULT.website else companyinfo.website end ,
 companyinfo.contactperson= case when companyinfo.contactperson='' OR companyinfo.contactperson IS NULL then RESULT.contactperson else companyinfo.contactperson end,companyinfo.country = case when companyinfo.country=1 OR companyinfo.country IS NULL then RESULT.country else companyinfo.country end,
 companyinfo.telphone=case when companyinfo.telphone='' OR companyinfo.telphone IS NULL then RESULT.telphone else companyinfo.telphone end,companyinfo.mobile= case when companyinfo.mobile='' OR companyinfo.mobile IS NULL then RESULT.mobile else companyinfo.mobile end ,
 companyinfo.fax= case when companyinfo.fax='' OR companyinfo.fax IS NULL then RESULT.fax else companyinfo.fax end, companyinfo.region= case when companyinfo.region=2 OR companyinfo.region IS NULL then RESULT.region else companyinfo.region end,companyinfo.urlorcatalog=RESULT.urlorcatalog,companyinfo.address= case when companyinfo.address='' OR companyinfo.address IS NULL then RESULT.address else companyinfo.address end,
 companyinfo.lastupdatedby=RESULT.lastupdatedby
FROM

(   
select TEMP1.companyname,TEMP1.website,TEMP1.contactperson,TEMP1.country, TEMP1.telphone , TEMP1.mobile, TEMP1.fax,TEMP1.region, TEMP1.urlorcatalog,TEMP1.address,TEMP1.lastupdatedby, TEMP1.DataID
from

        (   
            SELECT tmp.companyname,tmp.website,tmp.contactperson,tmp.country,tmp.telphone,tmp.mobile,tmp.fax, tmp.region,tmp.urlorcatalog,tmp.address,tmp.lastupdatedby,Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email                                                   
            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId     

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1       

) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataId =RESULT.DataID
```

Sometimes i get an error saying "Unable to add Timeout expired. Timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding" and through sql profiler i came to know the duration of the above query exceeds 30 secs.
The execution time of this query exceeds 30 seconds. How can i optimize the query so that the execution times becomes less then 30 seconds.

*Note the above query is the part of the procedure

Comment: Does your query always take 30+ seconds? What are the indexes you have on your tables? How much data exists in dbo.companyinfo, dbo.emailinfo and #TempTable?

Comment: No this is sometimes.Not always, i get this error "Unable to add Timeout expired. Timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding" . Data in dbo.companyinfo will be around 5 lakhs and in email info around thrice of companyinfo and #temptable will not have more than 200rows.

Comment: BTW, Lakh is a very indian unit :) So, dbo.companyinfo=500.000 rows, dbo.emailinfo=1.500.000 rows and #tempdb around 200... So, do you have any indexes? If so, what are their definitions? What are the column type (especially 'email') definitions in the three tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `merge` statement

```
MERGE INTO yourtable AS Target
USING (VALUES ('abc',
      'xyz@abc.com',
      'xyz',
      'pqr',
      0987765,
      087722,
      'South Africa')) AS Source (companyname, email_id, contact_name, designation, mobile, fax, country )
ON Target.companyname = Source.companyname
   AND Target.email_id = Source.email_id
   AND Target.contact_name = Source.contact_name
   AND Target.designation = Source.designation
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET companyname = CASE WHEN target.companyname IS NULL OR target.companyname = '' THEN Source.companyname ELSE target.companyname END,
             email_id = CASE WHEN target.email_id IS NULL OR target.email_id = '' THEN Source.email_id ELSE target.email_id END,
             contact_name = CASE WHEN target.contact_name IS NULL OR target.contact_name = '' THEN Source.contact_name ELSE target.contact_name END,
             designation = CASE WHEN target.designation IS NULL OR target.designation = '' THEN Source.designation ELSE target.designation END,
             mobile = CASE WHEN target.mobile IS NULL OR target.mobile = '' THEN Source.designation ELSE target.mobile END,
             fax = CASE WHEN target.fax IS NULL OR target.fax = '' THEN Source.fax ELSE target.fax END,
             country = CASE WHEN target.country IS NULL OR target.country = '' THEN Source.country ELSE target.country END
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (companyname,
          email_id,
          contact_name,
          designation,
          mobile,
          fax,
          country )
  VALUES (companyname,
          email_id,
          contact_name,
          designation,
          mobile,
          fax,
          country );
```

**Note :** Modifiy the join `ON` condition based on your requirement

Comment: Based on the OP's descirption `the existing data will be updated only for empty field` you probably want to change the `UPDATE` block *(something more like `field1 = CASE WHEN Target.field1 = '' OR Target.field1 IS NULL THEN Source.field1 ELSE Target.field1 END`, as used in the OP's originating SQL statement)*

Comment: Avoid using Merge statement, reason why you should avoid it have a look at this article ......................................... [`**Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement**`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there seems to be nothing inherently wrong with the query that would explain why it is taking so long. I would look at the query plan to see what it is doing.
I would also look into indenting (for readability) and improve the sub-query (as it seems overly complicated)